# Advantages of using `ng-include src`

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

I am working on an application which contains number of HTML and JS files.

In two different HTML files, one `div` structure (which uses `ng-repeat`) is going to be same. `Controller` which will render this `div` structure is also going to be the same.

`Style` of this div structure is going to be different on both HTML pages.

Now the question is , should I create a different HTML file which will have this `div` structure in it and then use `ng-class` to give different style to this structure. This generic HTML will be included using `ng-include src`.

or should I just copy-paste same `div` structure in two different HTML files? I feel advantage of doing this is that I don't have to maintain number of flags and use complex `ng-class` structure.

So to sum it all up, what are the advantages of including one HTML file using `ng-include src` over copying div structure in two different HTML files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advantage of `ng-include` over copy and paste here, as you said, is that of maintenance.  When it comes time to change the HTML content for some reason, you will not have to make changes in two (or more) places; just one.  So, if the HTML fragments really are identical and will change *together* as your application grows, use `ng-include`.

To style the two fragments differently: yes, you can `ng-class` to attach different css classes based on some basic logic.  As for the "complete `ng-class` structure" you mentioned, maybe there is a way for you to simplify that.  Show some more code and I can help you make it simpler.

And if at some point of time in future, the styles and of other attributes of this deviates, don't hesitate to fork the template and/or controller. Maintainability of each solution discussed in this example is dependent on how much commonality exists, which can change over time.